# Why do the uncertainties for a data set of natural logs have the same error?

Tags: error-analysis

I am attempting to plot the natural log of a set of values against another set of data on the x-axis in Python.[image: Plot of ln(\alpha) against energy in eV.]

However when I code the error propagation, as the error for $\ln(\alpha)$ is given by the error in $\alpha$ over its value, then the error on the y-axis will always be the same as shown in the 2D plot. This is not how I expected my data to look if I am being honest.
Should I include my error propagation in Python? If so can someone let me know if this still belongs on this site and not the coding version of this site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to the [Computational Science site](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

For small uncertainties, we use

\begin{align}
\ln(x±\Delta)
&= \ln x+ \ln(1± \delta)
\\& ≈(\ln x) ±\delta
\end{align}

Here $\Delta$ is the *absolute* uncertainty, with the same units as $x$, while $\delta=\Delta/x$ is the dimensionless *fractional* uncertainty. For example, if $x= 9 \text{ unit}$ has a fractional uncertainty of $\delta=1\%$, we would say that the logarithm of $(9\pm 0.09)\text{ unit}$ is the dimensionless result $(2\pm 0.01)$. At least, in the approximation where $9=e^2$, so that I don't need to grab a calculator for some irrelevant digits, and where we sweep the problem of dimensionful logarithms under the rug.

The thing to notice here is that the *fractional* uncertainty on the variable becomes the *absolute* uncertainty on its logarithm.

Your error bars all seem to be about $\pm 0.25$, suggesting you have assumed a uniform 25% uncertainty on each of your $\alpha$. That's unusually large, and the variations in your points suggest it is too large — perhaps just a typo.